# Access union query odd characters.

Tags: ms-access, union, ms-access-2013

I have a database where there is a union query that is pulling some data for a report. This has been working fine for some time and I had to switch a field in a table from short text to long text with rich text in order to support additional font options. In doing so, when I run the query the field in question is coming back with funny characters. The table is called tbl_Process and the field is Process. I have tried setting indexes on that field but it's not helping. I can fumble my way around union queries a bit, but they are a weak point and I'm hoping someone could take a look at the query to see if they have any suggestions.

```
SELECT tbl_Areas.Area_Detail AS Area, tbl_Areas.Product, tbl_Areas.Area_ID AS [Area Code], tbl_Areas.Revision AS [Area Book Revision], tbl_Processes.Group, tbl_Processes.Serial_Number AS [Process Serial Number], [Group] & "-" & [Product_Family] & [tbl_Products].[Size] & "-" & [tbl_Processes].[Serial_Number] & "-" & [tbl_Areas].[Area_ID] & "-" & [tbl_Processes]![Revision] AS [Document Name], tbl_Processes.Process, tbl_Processes.Revision AS [Process Revision], tbl_Finished_Product_Families.Common_Name AS [Product Family], tbl_Products.Size AS [Product Size], tbl_Models.Model_Definition AS [Product Model], tbl_ECN.Date_Published AS [ECN Date], Max(tbl_ECN.Revision) AS [ECN Revision], tbl_ECN.Engineer AS [Engineer of Record], tbl_Processes.Sequential_Position
FROM (tbl_Models INNER JOIN (tbl_Finished_Product_Families INNER JOIN tbl_Products ON tbl_Finished_Product_Families.Finished_Product_Family = tbl_Products.Product_Family) ON tbl_Models.Model = tbl_Products.Model) INNER JOIN (tbl_ECN RIGHT JOIN (tbl_Areas INNER JOIN tbl_Processes ON tbl_Areas.Area_ID = tbl_Processes.Area) ON tbl_ECN.Serial_Number = tbl_Processes.Serial_Number) ON tbl_Products.Product_ID = tbl_Processes.Product
GROUP BY tbl_Areas.Area_Detail, tbl_Areas.Product, tbl_Areas.Area_ID, tbl_Areas.Revision, tbl_Processes.Group, tbl_Processes.Serial_Number, [Group] & "-" & [Product_Family] & [tbl_Products].[Size] & "-" & [tbl_Processes].[Serial_Number] & "-" & [tbl_Areas].[Area_ID] & "-" & [tbl_Processes]![Revision], tbl_Processes.Process, tbl_Processes.Revision, tbl_Finished_Product_Families.Common_Name, tbl_Products.Size, tbl_Models.Model_Definition, tbl_ECN.Date_Published, tbl_ECN.Engineer, tbl_Processes.Sequential_Position

UNION SELECT DISTINCT tbl_Areas.Area_Detail, tbl_Areas.Product, tbl_Areas.Area_ID, tbl_Areas.Revision, "OP Book" AS Expr1, Null AS Expr2, "OP-" & [Product_Family] & [tbl_Products].[Size] & "-0000-" & [tbl_Areas].[Area_ID] AS [Document Name], Null AS Expr4, Null AS Expr3, tbl_Finished_Product_Families.Common_Name, tbl_Products.Size, tbl_Models.Model_Definition, Null AS Expr5, Null AS Expr6, Null AS Expr7, 100 AS Expr8
FROM (tbl_Models INNER JOIN (tbl_Finished_Product_Families INNER JOIN tbl_Products ON tbl_Finished_Product_Families.Finished_Product_Family = tbl_Products.Product_Family) ON tbl_Models.Model = tbl_Products.Model) INNER JOIN (tbl_Areas INNER JOIN tbl_Processes ON tbl_Areas.Area_ID = tbl_Processes.Area) ON tbl_Products.Product_ID = tbl_Processes.Product;
```

Comment: You could try looking at each piece of the Union separately to see where the odd characters are coming from - it sounds like it might be a daat problem more than a query problem.

Comment: I know if I build a query to look at just that field it will display properly. I've even taken chunks of it and it will display correctly. For some reason, when I run the whole query, it has trouble with just this field.  I've made a test copy of the database and if I switch the field back to short text it will function properly. The problem is that the data may need to be longer than 255 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following Don George's suggestion, I found that if I switched `tbl_Processes.Process to  First(tbl_Processes.Process) AS Process` it displayed the data correctly and didn't lose anything. I did need to adjust a couple of queries that referenced this one, but now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform aggregate functions on Memo fields you can get some weird results. This page explains the issues http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, that definitely explains why it was occurring and why switching it to first fixed the problem.